# Kill thread-based logging instance ungracefully?

Tags: c#, multithreading, logging

Application logging is done using plain and boring log files via a custom rolling flat file logging library. To lower the amount of write accesses to the hard disk, logging events get queued for either when a) a maximum queue item limit is reached or b) a certain amount of time has passed. For the time interval aspect, the logging library runs a thread which flushes the queue periodically.

Now, the logging instance is statically accessible, singleton and application wide (used in many other libraries) and sometimes it happens (altough it shouldn't) that a developer forgets to dispose the flushing thread with the result that, even if the application is 'closed', the thread keeps running and the application has to be killed via a task-manager, which is far from ideal.

So I'm wondering: Is there a possibility to automatically close the thread on application exit? I know about  `BackgroundWorker`, `Timer` and `Threadpool`, but are those good solutions for that certain task? Or better stick with the 'classic' `Thread`?

Comment: tried nlog or log4net?

Comment: @DanielMošmondor I am familiar with nlog, log4net, Enterprise Application Logging Block etc.. While those libraries are neat, they are simply way to much for what we need. :)

Comment: Are you using WinForms or WPF ?

Comment: @igelineau WPF and ASPX. But I don't see any relation to logging.. ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detecting that an application is about to exit is very specific to what kind of application you're running.

I don't know much about Aspx, but in WPF you could use the following code to hook up the Exit event of the System.Windows.Application class and close your thread gracefully in the event handler.

Also, you should always avoid killing a thread instead of shutting down gracefully, when it's possible, it can lead to inconsistencies because you have no way of controlling when it will really exit.  Instead, you should periodically check for an exit condition, like in the code below.

```
public static class MyLogger
{
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        if(IsWPFApplication())
            Application.Current.Exit += Application_Exit;

        //start flush thread and other initializations...
    }

    private static bool IsWPFApplication()
    {
        Dispatcher dispatcher = Dispatcher.FromThread(Thread.CurrentThread);
        return (dispatcher != null);
    }

    private static void Application_Exit(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Shutdown();
    }

    private static void Shutdown()
    {
        ExitRequested = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a great approach and solves my problem right on the spot. I didn't even thought about the Application.Current.Exit event. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Diagnostic.Process.GetCurrentProcess.Kill though if you are using dot net 4.0 I would recommend using tasks.  Here is an excellent resource that I would recommend http://www.albahari.com/threading/.